# Using @SerializedName with hyphen not working

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, json-serialization, ktor-client

I am trying to deserialize this JSON response into an object and one of my keys has a hyphen on it. Unfortunately, Kotlin does not support hyphens in variable names which is why I used @SerializedName() but it is still now working.
Any clues as to why?

JSON Response

```
[
    {
        "dateCreated": "07-22-2021",
        "comments": "Comment",
        "vehicle_type": "Sedan",
        "name": "Leagacy Nissan Template",
        "template-type": "", //this is giving me the problem
        "template_uses_type": "Both"
        ...
    }
]
```

My object:

```
@Serializable
data class SpinDataResponse(
    val dateCreated:String,
    val comments: String,
    val vehicle_type:String,
    val name:String,
    @SerializedName("template-type") val template_type:String,
    val template_uses_type:String,
    ...
)
```

Error:

> I/System.out: Error: Unexpected JSON token at offset 120: Encountered
> an unknown key 'template-type'.
> Use 'ignoreUnknownKeys = true' in 'Json {}' builder to ignore unknown keys.
> JSON input: ....."name": "Nissan PathFinder", "template-type": "", "template_.....

I don't want to ignore the unknown key because I actually need it.

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the JSON?

Comment: I am working with a Ktor client using Kotlinx serialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `@SerialName("")`?

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/-serial-name/index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254149/kotlinx-serialization-how-to-parse-to-different-varaiable-name-than-the-exact I was wrongly using the annotation for GSON, thanks