# kotlinx serializer decode snake case to camel case without serial name

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

### Question

Hi I'm new to kotlinx serialization. the json is snake case, and kotlin data class uses camel case. is there a way to parse snake case by using custom serilizer and deserializer?

I know how to do...

```kotlin
val format = Json { namingStrategy = JsonNamingStrategy.SnakeCase }

val project = format.decodeFromString<Project>("""{"project_name":"kotlinx.coroutines", "project_owner":"Kotlin"}""")
assertThat(project.projectName).isEqualTo("kotlinx.coroutines")
assertThat(project.projectOwner).isEqualTo("Kotlin")
```

but I want to override deserializer and place this logic inside of companion object. is this possible?

### My code

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveKind
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveSerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.decodeStructure
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonNamingStrategy

@kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
private val json = Json { namingStrategy = JsonNamingStrategy.SnakeCase }

@Serializable(PaymentInfo.Companion::class)
data class PaymentInfo(
    val paymentNo: String,
    val paymentDate: String,
    val paymentService: String,
    
    ) {
    companion object: KSerializer<PaymentInfo> {
        // what descriptor should I use?
        override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("PaymentInfo", PrimitiveKind.)

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: PaymentInfo) {
            // what to do ?
        }
        override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): PaymentInfo {
            // what to do ?
        }
    }
}
```

### Edited

I want to avoid adding `@SerialName` to every member!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlinx.serialization : How to parse to different varaiable name than the exact name of JSON key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254149/kotlinx-serialization-how-to-parse-to-different-varaiable-name-than-the-exact)

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately, no. I forgot to mention, I want to avoid `@SerialName` I'm afraid that that's too much labor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `@SerialName`

First, I just want to mention that I don't understand your wish to avoid `@SerialName`. [You mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471198/kotlinx-serializer-decode-snake-case-to-camel-case-without-serial-name/77471673#comment136578128_77471198):

> I'm afraid that that's too much labor.

But as you'll see in the next section of this answer, the custom serializer is quite a bit of code. And the same thing can be accomplished with just:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class PaymentInfo(
    @SerialName("payment_no") val paymentNo: String,
    @SerialName("payment_date") val paymentDate: String,
    @SerialName("payment_service") val paymentService: String
)
```

For something as simple as changing the serial name of a property, I strongly recommend you use `@SerialName` instead of writing a completely custom serializer.

---

## Custom Serializer

If you really want to avoid `@SerialName`, then you can customize the serialized names via a custom serializer. If you have:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable(PaymentInfoSerializer::class)
data class PaymentInfo(
    val paymentNo: String,
    val paymentDate: String,
    val paymentService: String
)
```

And you want the following custom names:

| Class property | Serial Name |
| --- | --- |
| `paymentNo` | `payment_no` |
| `paymentDate` | `payment_date` |
| `paymentService` | `payment_service` |

Then the custom `PaymentInfoSerializer` might look like this:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.buildClassSerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.element
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.*

// You can move this to the companion object of PaymentInfo if
// you really want to.
object PaymentInfoSerializer : KSerializer<PaymentInfo> {

    override val descriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("PaymentInfo") {
        element<String>("payment_no")
        element<String>("payment_date")
        element<String>("payment_service")
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: PaymentInfo) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.paymentNo)
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 1, value.paymentDate)
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 2, value.paymentService)
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): PaymentInfo {
        return decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            var paymentNo = ""
            var paymentDate = ""
            var paymentService = ""
            while (true) {
                when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                    0 -> paymentNo = decoder.decodeString()
                    1 -> paymentDate = decoder.decodeString()
                    2 -> paymentService = decoder.decodeString()
                    CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> break
                    else -> error("Unknown index: $index")
                }
            }
            PaymentInfo(paymentNo, paymentDate, paymentService)
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Serializers](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#serializers) chapter of the *Kotlin Serialization Guide* for more information.

Here is the above serializer in use:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

fun main() {
    val original = PaymentInfo("42", "2023-11-12", "foo")
    val encoded = Json.encodeToString(original)
    val decoded = Json.decodeFromString<PaymentInfo>(encoded)
    println(original)
    println(encoded)
    println(decoded)
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
PaymentInfo(paymentNo=42, paymentDate=2023-11-12, paymentService=foo)
{"payment_no":"42","payment_date":"2023-11-12","payment_service":"foo"}
PaymentInfo(paymentNo=42, paymentDate=2023-11-12, paymentService=foo)
```

Comment: Thanks! wow... I never thought that implement custom serializer would be that hard...! I might embrace `@SerialName` as you said!